# Не переведено пояснение для отклоненной модератором тревоги на сообщение

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex, тревоги

Вот сам [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469552/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89) и цитата части уведомления:

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Поясенение модератора о том, когда обычно используется такая причина отклонения тревоги:

- Сообщение отмечено как спам, но не является спамом. (Например, это просто ссылка на какой-то продукт, без рекламных целей)
- Сообщение отмечено как оскорбительное, но фактически содержит не оскорбления, а конструктивную критику.
- В тревоге "требуется вмешательство модератора" участник сформулировал просьбу или предложение; модератор принял решение отклонить их.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я предлагаю следующий вариант перевода:

> модератор проверил ваше обращение и не нашел причин для его удовлетворения